# How to animate a rectangle and label in svg or css? (smooth split color animation)

Tags: css, svg

I want to animate a rectangle based on some percentage to smoothly split into 2 colors and at the same time the percentages to increase/decrease in the label like in the one below:

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 2165.4 1686.6" style="enable-background:new 0 0 2165.4 1686.6;" xml:space="preserve">
  <style type="text/css">
    .st1 { fill: #54A4DB; }
    .st2 { font-family: 'Helvetica'; }
    .st3 { fill: #FFFFFF; }
    .st4 { font-size: 40px; }
  </style>
  <rect id="zone5" x="670.4" y="773.2" class="st1" width="1192.8" height="150.2"/>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1176.7595 860.7599)" class="st3 st2 st4">1.00/0.00</text>
</svg>
```

For the split effect I thought, in the worst case, of using two rectangles and animate one of them using

```
<animate attributeName="width" from="0" to="1192.8" dur="3s" fill="freeze"/>
```

but I much appreciate any other simpler method, if there is one.

But for the label I don't have any idea how to smoothly change the value from one to the other

Comment: in other words you want to create a progress bar?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is the same thing :)

Comment: in this case you will find a ton of examples in the net